# arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ can't link xerces-c

Tags: c++, arm, g++, gnu, xerces-c

arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ can't compile code that uses the xerces-c parser. Specifically, it can't seem to locate the xerces-c library even when I specify the full path with the I- flag or link it with -lxerces-c.  However, when I compile with the generic g++ parser, everything works fine.  Moreover, g++ works fine when I move around the xerces-c directories.

The code for g++ compilation:

```
g++ -pthread -g -c -std=c++0x src/MyFile.cpp -o $(TARGET_DIR)/MyFile.o -lxerces-c
```

The code for arm-linux-gnueabi-g++:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -pthread -g -c -std=c++0x src/MyFile.cpp -o $(TARGET_DIR)/MyFile.o -lxerces-c
```

This is the error I receive:

```
src/myFile.cpp fatal error: xerces/util/PlatformUtils.hpp: No such file or directory
#include <xerces/util/Platform/utils.hpp
compilation terminated
```

I also tried removing the angle brackets enclosing the xerces library and replacing them with quotations so the path wouldn't get messed up.

Comment: You haven't specified the include directories where the headers are to be found (-I option).

Comment: @Aconcagua Could you expand on that?

Comment: `/this/is/my/path/to/xerces/util/Platform/utils.hpp`, then you'd have `gcc -I/this/is/my/path/to [...]` (it is a capital 'i'). Similarly, you can tell with -L option where to search for library files (if later on the linker does not find axerces-c.lib).

Comment: Thanks. How come this compiles on g++? What's the difference between g++ and arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ when it comes to linking libraries?

Comment: Seems as if xerces added its include path to g++'s default configuration somehow, but that's rather a guess... Both your local compiler and the arm cross compiler support the same options (at very least, they are both g++), so if you explicitly specify include and library path, you cannot fail in either case...

Comment: By the way, are you aware that you need to compile xerces for arm separately? Host and arm version of library won't be binary compatible!